# Error while installing slapd

Tags: debian, openldap

I need some help for solving this problem when I try to install slapd package on Debian from testing repositories.

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  slapd
0 actualizados, 1 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 2 no actualizados.
Necesito descargar 1.344 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 4.091 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
Des:1 http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/ testing/main slapd amd64 2.4.31-1+nmu2+b1 [1.344 kB]
Descargados 1.344 kB en 50seg. (26,4 kB/s)                                                                                                                             
Preconfigurando paquetes ...
Seleccionando el paquete slapd previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 260763 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Desempaquetando slapd (de .../slapd_2.4.31-1+nmu2+b1_amd64.deb) ...
Procesando disparadores para man-db ...
Configurando slapd (2.4.31-1+nmu2+b1) ...
  Omitting slapd configuration as requested.
insserv: warning: script 'K01subversion' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'subversion' missing LSB tags and overrides
[warn] No configuration file was found for slapd at /etc/ldap/slapd.conf. ... (warning).
invoke-rc.d: initscript slapd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error al procesar slapd (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 slapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I do not understand why is trying to find the slapd.conf file, because this versión of slapd(2.4.31) uses cn=config.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I solved it using simply `dpkg-reconfigure --force slapd`. Hope it helps for other users that have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) slapd.conf is still supported in OpenLDAP 2.4.

The Debian package maintainer may therefore still support it as well and have a check for the presence of the slapd.conf as part of the init script, maybe as a fall-back when no cn=config is detected either, to prevent OpenLDAP from starting without any configuration.

You omitted the download/installation options you used; but the warning: `Omitting slapd configuration as requested.` makes it sound like you explicitly omitted the installation of a default configuration.

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow slapd
```

appears to be suggested in the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup) when it isn't set up correctly.

Comment: I am not omitting any configuration. I am using the classical `apt-get install slapd`. Nothing else.